# How did the contract size grow after removing couple of lines?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-deployment, hardhat

This is surely not a general case, but a specific one.

I have a large smart contract (22.572 KB) and I am trying to make it smaller.
Here is a chunk of the contract:

```
    modifier onlyValidTokenId(bytes32 composedTokenId) {
        _onlyValidTokenId(composedTokenId);

        _;
    }

    function _onlyValidTokenId(bytes32 composedTokenId) internal view {
        bytes16[2] memory decomposedTokenId = _decomposeTokenId(composedTokenId);

        uint256 composedTokenIdAsNumber = uint256(composedTokenId);
        if (composedTokenIdAsNumber == 0 || composedTokenIdAsNumber > collectionTokenSupplyCap(decomposedTokenId[0])) {
            revert CardTokenInvalidTokenId(composedTokenId);
        }
    }
```

Now regardless of what the code says or does, and ignoring the rest of the contract, I did this:

```
    modifier onlyValidTokenId(bytes32 composedTokenId) {
        bytes16[2] memory decomposedTokenId = _decomposeTokenId(composedTokenId);
        
        uint256 composedTokenIdAsNumber = uint256(composedTokenId);
        if (composedTokenIdAsNumber == 0 || composedTokenIdAsNumber > collectionTokenSupplyCap(decomposedTokenId[0])) {
            revert CardTokenInvalidTokenId(composedTokenId);
        }

        _;
    }
```

thinking the contract size will shrink cause I removed couple of lines.
But after compiling, the size of my contract went up to 22.702 KB.
How is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifiers are inlined into their respective functions (i.e. their code is copied).

In your previous example, the code size is shorter because the modifier contains only a reference to an internal function, while now it contains the full bytecode.

At the same time, the second code example would use less gas (no jump to the internal function).